# FIFO server program

Tags: c, linux, client-server, mkfifo

[image]

The above program i have typed in linux. It basically has to connect a client and server in separate terminals. But when i run them in the correct order, i.e

1. Compile server -> run server
2. Compile client - > run client

The terminals just dont do anything. It doesnt even print the `"Trying to connect"` part of the first `printf` statement. What is the mistake here?

**EDIT**

I checked for return value of `mkfifo` as @parapura rajkumar said. But Still it remains the same. Here is my changed code for server.

```
if(mkfifo("fifo1",0666)<0) {
  printf("Error");
}
if(mkfifo("fifo2",0666)<0) {
  printf("Error");
}
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: Unless you are going to print more on one line using several `printf` calls, it is advised to end the `printf` with a new-line (`\n`) as that will flush the output so it's shown in the console. Then you don't need `fflush`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made deadlock. Server wait open("fifo1",O_RDONLY) and client wait open("fifo2",O_RDONLY).

Edit client.c:

```
int writefd = open("fifo1",O_WRONLY);
int readfd = open("fifo2",O_RDONLY);
```

Comment: To be more explicit, opening a fifo normally blocks until someone else opens it  too so that they can be connected.  (At least, by default -- it can be opened in non-blocking mode, though this makes things more complicated.)